# Delphi 5 Send Email With Indy

Tags: email, delphi, indy

I'm trying to send an email using Indy 10 on Delphi 5, what happens is that it doesn't want to authenticate as it shows me the "Nooo" message. So far I have this code here (which I got from another Stack Overflow question). I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me since it apparently did for the other person... Maybe I missed something, I replaced the senderemail and receiveremail with 2 of my actual mails and the password of course.

*EDIT*

So that's where I am right now, it pops a "Must issue a STARTTLS command first." error now however... I'm really confused with this...

*EDIT 2*

So I managed to make it work, here's the final result. Feel free to tell me if something isn't done properly... I had an Access Violation until I added the "IdSMTP.Authenticate;" line before sending the message!

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    IdSMTP: TIdSMTP;
    Email: TIdMessage;
    SSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
    IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
    SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    Email := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
        SSLHandler.MaxLineAction := maException;
        SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
        SSLHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
        SSLHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

        IdSMTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler;
        IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
        IdSMTP.Port := 587;
        IdSMTP.Username := 'email@gmail.com';
        IdSMTP.Password := 'password';
        IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;

        Email.From.Address := 'email@gmail.com';
        Email.Recipients.EmailAddresses := 'secondemail@gmail.com';
        Email.Subject := 'Test subject';
        Email.Body.Text := 'Test body';

        IdSMTP.Connect;
        if IdSMTP.Connected then
        begin
            IdSMTP.Authenticate;
            IdSMTP.Send(Email);
            IdSMTP.Disconnect;
        end;
    finally
        Email.Free;
        SSLHandler.Free;
        IdSMTP.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that `AuthType=satDefault` does not work with all servers.  It uses 
the `AUTH LOGIN` command, which is not secure, and some servers have dropped 
support for it.  You should consider using `AuthType=satSASL` with the 
`TIdSMTP.SASLMechanisms` collection instead. You do not need to call Authenticate() manually

Comment: Gmail uses 25, 465 and 587 for SMTP, but since almost all isps block 25, 465 is the preferred SMTP with SSL for gmail, and 587 is the preferred SMTP with TLS port.

Comment: GMail can use settings which does not allow access to your program - try to find "Access for less secure apps" in your settings.

Comment: You do not need to enable "Access for less secure apps" if you have 2-factor authentication enabled and have created an app-specific password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
  IdSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSMTP.UseTLS := utNoTLSSupport;
    IdSMTP.Host := 'smtp.gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Port := 25;
    IdSMTP.AuthType := satDefault;
    IdSMTP.Username := 'SenderEmail@gmail.com';
    IdSMTP.Password := 'Password';        

    IdMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
    try
        IdMessage.From.Name := 'My Name';
        IdMessage.From.Address := 'SenderEmail@gmail.com';
        IdMessage.Subject := 'E-mail subject';
        IdMessage.Body.Add('E-mail body.');
        IdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'ReceiverEmail@gmail.com';           
        IdMessage.ReceiptRecipient.Name := 'Name';

        if not IdSMTP.Connected then
          IdSMTP.Connect;

        IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);

     finally
          IdMessage.Free;
          IdSMTP.Disconnect;
     end;

  finally
    IdSMTP.Free;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Free;
```

Comment: It tells me "SSL IOHandler is required for this setting" even though I added the "IdSMTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;" line... Strange

Comment: Is "SSLHandler" supposed to be "IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1"?

Comment: Ok, try to move `IdSMTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;` in the top (see update) or try to just Drop an SSL IOHandler

Comment: Ok that seems to have done the trick however now I get an access violation error.

Comment: "IdSMTP.Send(IdMessage);"

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause an AccessVioation exception. However, do note that `utUseExplicitTLS` does not work on Gmail's port 25, only on port 587.  On port 465, use `utUseImplicitTLS`. On port 25, use `utNoTLSSupport` instead and do not assign the SSL IOHandler.

Comment: Hmmm, I lost the access violation error but now it tells me "Must issue a STARTTLS command first."

Comment: Nevermind it's working now! Thank you both for your help!